# How does typegen work with metadata v14?

Tags: polkadot-js, types, metadata, custom-types

In the new metadata v14, a `types.json` is no longer required for custom types. How does this affect the typegen procedure in the docs which require us to specify these types in the `definition.ts` for each module we declared in runtime before running the `types-from-defs` script of the `@polkadotjs/typegen` package (which is required for `types-from-metadata`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that the actual definitions are basically deprecated. However, it does still play a (small) role in that the RPC types are not carried in the metadata. (This will change in the future and is on the issue list in Substrate, but we are not there as of yet.)

For metadata v14 chains, just pass a completely empty `types` in `definitions.ts`, i.e. if no extra RPC type overrides and/or no extra RPC endpoints, just leave the `types` entry blank.

In this case it should generate no extra definitions from the empty `types`, but will create the lookups and all additional interfaces for augmentation.

(There may be dragons... while is gets used exactly in this fashion in the API itself to generate augmentation for Substrate master, Kusama and Polkadot, some brave early-adopters did have some small hiccups which is detailed in the JS API issues.)